# NodeJs and Keycloak Integration giving 403?

Tags: node.js, keycloak, keycloak-connect, keycloak-nodejs-connect

I just took the demo code from this [Github](https://github.com/ddezoysa/keycloak-nodejs-microservice) 
So i change the `keycloak-config.json`

```
 var keycloakConfig ={
        clientId: 'my-api',
        bearerOnly: true,
        serverUrl: 'https://<IPADDRESS>:8443/auth/',
        realm: 'myrealm',
        credentials: {
            secret: '99e71ca7-f25b-40b5-87ed-0af2656b52ac'
        }
    };
```

Now to access the api endpoint first i will generate the token 
[image]

With the help of above token i am trying to access secure API
[image]

But it will fail with the error

> 403: Access Denied

Here is code

```
router.get('/user', keycloak.protect(), function(req, res){
    res.send("Hello User");
});
```

Even this also giving same

```
router.get('/user', keycloak.protect('user'), function(req, res){
    res.send("Hello User");
});
```

I followed [this](https://medium.com/devops-dudes/securing-node-js-express-rest-apis-with-keycloak-a4946083be51) link for this demo code

Comment: do you get some additional errors on the nodejs side? otherwise I can just do some wild guessing ;-) you are accessing keycloak over https, is the used cert trusted by nodejs? if you send an `access_token` to nodejs, this token need to be validated with the realms public key. this key is normally fetched from a kc-ednpoint, maybe this isn't possible in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After i found the solution i saw the comment as well ,my solution and comment matched so we have to make following changes,in place of `credentials` we have to use `realmPublicKey`

```
var keycloakConfig ={
    clientId: 'my-api',
    bearerOnly: 'true',
    serverUrl: 'https://<IPADDRESS>:8443/auth/',
    realm: 'myrealm',
    sslRequired: 'external',
    realmPublicKey: 'MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAhGpeNPTzIA0SpqWtOU27C3lCdHkLzWiYc3voiBZvvZdvk4wW96JymHlX2b0weDnkYfurxIRehRA0sLK8w2vjb3X9TdKOcsiQzHlWDQuA3Wu7WeDGcvv8dyDk+bMOSkqn7bMlOUm6CXxA7RrjKuDj8mseqabXNjnPgAPL6MQOWtO4RFMdPQX11fYShXrK9ELS3CqN3RrXBazzwNsreKxfuMtR4vtZCVJHYaZZMiLmWU1G5Xsh/tHje2AVLPkt3ncchyKsrkCdP9PWsYK5dMkKsDbA03JOq7azDDlhqgT2pUNB3dZ1b9sKQXqPC6ZSieVJcm6WAj8DJcjoYOgZjgm2/8X1fwIDAQAB',

};
```

Just adding what @Evil_skunk written

> do you get some additional errors on the nodejs side? otherwise I can
>   just do some wild guessing ;-) you are accessing keycloak over https,
>   is the used cert trusted by nodejs? if you send an access_token to
>   nodejs, this token need to be validated with the realms public key.
>   this key is normally fetched from a kc-ednpoint, maybe this isn't
>   possible in your case

Comment: I have the same issue but it doesn't work for me. What am I doing wrong any idea?

Comment: @Shamim You have to tell the details then only i can help you.

Answer (score 1):

In you KeyCloack configuration variable, you can use `credentials` and not `realmPublicKey`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. Also used the example code from [here](https://medium.com/devops-dudes/securing-node-js-express-rest-apis-with-keycloak-a4946083be51)

The only adjustment to the example code is creating the session. here there was always an error message with the example code.

**My code:**

index.js:

```
// index.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

const session = require('express-session');
const memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();
app.use(session({
  secret: 'some secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: memoryStore
}));

const keycloak = require('./config/keycloak-config.js').initKeycloak(memoryStore);
app.use(keycloak.middleware({
  logout: '/logout',
  admin: '/'
}));

const testController = require('./controller/test-controller.js');
app.use('/test', testController);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send("Server is up!");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

keycloak-config.js:

```
// keycloak-config.js
var session = require('express-session');
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');

let _keycloak;

var keycloakConfig = {
    clientId: 'test-client',
    bearerOnly: true,
    serverUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
    realm: 'test',
    credentials: {
        secret: 'xS9K7RpUah5PzWQZh6BaAGX8Ochr6RY6'
    }
};

function initKeycloak(memoryStore) {
    if (_keycloak) {
        console.warn("Trying to init Keycloak again!");
        return _keycloak;
    } 
    else {
        console.log("Initializing Keycloak...");
        _keycloak = new Keycloak({ 
          store: memoryStore
        }
        , keycloakConfig
        );
        return _keycloak;
    }
}

function getKeycloak() {
    if (!_keycloak){
        console.error('Keycloak has not been initialized. Please called init first.');
    } 
    return _keycloak;
}

module.exports = {
    initKeycloak,
    getKeycloak
};
```

test-controller.js:

```
// test-controller.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const keycloak = require('../config/keycloak-config.js').getKeycloak();

router.get('/anonymous', function(req, res){
    res.send("Hello Anonymous");
});

router.get('/user', keycloak.protect('user'), function(req, res){
    res.send("Hello User");
});

router.get('/admin', keycloak.protect('admin'), function(req, res){
    res.send("Hello Admin");
});

router.get('/all-user', keycloak.protect(['user','admin']), function(req, res){
    res.send("Hello All User");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Change the `bearerOnly` option to `false`

```
var keycloakConfig = {
  clientId: "nodejs-microservice",
  bearerOnly: false,
  serverUrl: "http://localhost:8083/auth",
  realm: "Demo-Realm",
  credentials: {
    secret: "8ZkObGg73gr26TtAPE9TKVC7QmQikNMx",
  },
};
```